# Unhandled Exception: User denied permissions to access the device's location

Tags: flutter, geolocator

```
     getUserLocationAddress() async
     {
        Position newPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
         desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high
        );

        position = newPosition;

        placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
           position!.latitude, position!.longitude
        );

        Placemark pMark = placemarks![0];

        String fullAddress = '${pMark.subThoroughfare} 
          ${pMark.thoroughfare}, ${pMark.subLocality} ${pMark.locality}, ${pMark.subAdministrativeArea}, ${pMark.administrativeArea} ${pMark.postalCode}, ${pMark.country}';

         _locationController.text = fullAddress;

         _flatNumber.text = '${pMark.subThoroughfare} ${pMark.thoroughfare}, ${pMark.subLocality} ${pMark.locality}';
         _city.text = '${pMark.subAdministrativeArea}, ${pMark.administrativeArea} ${pMark.postalCode}';
         _state.text = '${pMark.country}';
         _completeAddress.text = fullAddress;
      }
```

I have added this function onPressed() but it doest record and show the location..

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtOQM.jpg)
even after pressing on 'Get My Location' it doesn't show location. pls help

Answer (score 1):

Every app needs permission to access the device's location.

The code below, extracted from https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator, shows how to request it.

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

/// Determine the current position of the device.
///
/// When the location services are not enabled or permissions
/// are denied the `Future` will return an error.
Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  // Test if location services are enabled.
  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // Location services are not enabled don't continue
    // accessing the position and request users of the 
    // App to enable the location services.
    return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
      // requesting permissions again (this is also where
      // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale 
      // returned true. According to Android guidelines
      // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
      return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
    }
  }
  
  if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
    // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately. 
    return Future.error(
      'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
  } 

  // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
  // continue accessing the position of the device.
  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
}
```